# How to enable anyone to view Google BigQuery related project

Tags: google-api, google-bigquery

I followed the tutorial here

```
https://developers.google.com/bigquery/articles/dashboard#enablebigqueryapi
```

and created a sample application to query Google BigQuery. But only I with my email id and password can view the project.

How can I make changes so that anyone can view the project online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do, and what you mean by "anyone."

**If you want to have the user authorize access to the API**: *(This is the authorization flow described in the dashboard tutorial)* You can't make access to a Google Developer Project totally public (you would not want to do this anyway). However you can make a [BigQuery dataset available to anyone with a Google Account](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/datasets/update) (you can toggle these permissions using the API, the Web UI, or the bq command line tool).

Every user who accesses BigQuery in this way, even if they are not part of your project, will need to sign into to Google Developer Console and accept the BigQuery terms of service. This flow is called web server authorization, [read more about it here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorization#web-server-applications).

**If you want to make a dashboard open to anyone:**
You will likely want the application itself to be authorized to have access to the BigQuery API. In this flow, you will want to use an "[service account authorization flow](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorization#service-accounts)," and likely you want to use [App Engine Service Accounts](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorization#service-accounts-appengine). See this page for how to build this type of authorization.